# .map is undefined when mapping through the profile.education array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object

I'm experiencing some difficulty with trying to map through an objects property which is an array of objects. I get back an error message that .map is undefined, basically saying there is no array. The array i want to map through is education. At times I also get a proxy error that the route is timing out and this loses the profile data i'm fetching and the profile object is empty. Is there anyway to fix this too.

My model:

```
 import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const profileSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    experience: [
      {
        title: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        company: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        location: {
          type: String,
        },
        from: {
          type: Date,
          required: true,
        },
        to: {
          type: Date,
        },
        current: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
        description: {
          type: String,
        },
      },
    ],
    education: [
      {
        level: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
          enum: [
            'None',
            'GCSE or equivalent',
            'A-Level or equivalent',
            'Certificate of Higher Education',
            'Diploma of Higher Education',
            'Bachelors',
            'Masters',
            'PhD',
          ],
        },
        school: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        fieldofstudy: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        city: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        from: {
          type: Date,
          required: true,
        },
        to: {
          type: Date,
        },
        current: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
      },
    ],
    skills: [
      {
        name: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        yearsExperience: {
          type: Number,
          required: true,
        },
      },
    ],
    additionalInfo: {
      desiredJobTitle: {
        type: String,
      },
      desiredJobType: {
        type: [String],
      },
      desiredSalary: {
        type: Number,
      },
      readyToWork: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
      },
      relocate: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
      },
    },
    savedJobs: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Job',
      },
    ],
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
)

const Profile = mongoose.model('Profile', profileSchema)

export default Profile
```

My action:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import {
  PROFILE_DETAILS_REQUEST,
  PROFILE_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
  PROFILE_DETAILS_FAIL,
  PROFILE_CREATE_REQUEST,
  PROFILE_CREATE_SUCCESS,
  PROFILE_CREATE_FAIL,
  PROFILE_CREATE_EDUCATION_REQUEST,
  PROFILE_CREATE_EDUCATION_SUCCESS,
  PROFILE_CREATE_EDUCATION_FAIL,
} from '../constants/profileConstants'
import { setAlert } from './alertActions'

export const getCurrentProfile = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: PROFILE_DETAILS_REQUEST })

    const {
      userLogin: { userData },
    } = getState()

    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userData.token}`,
      },
    }

    const { data } = await axios.get('/api/v1/profile/me', config)

    dispatch({
      type: PROFILE_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    })
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: PROFILE_DETAILS_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.error
          ? error.response.data.error
          : null,
    })
  }
}
```

My reducer:

```
export const profileDetailsReducer = (state = { profile: {} }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PROFILE_DETAILS_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
      }
    case PROFILE_DETAILS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        loading: false,
        profile: action.payload,
      }

    case PROFILE_DETAILS_FAIL:
      return {
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload,
      }
    case PROFILE_DETAILS_RESET:
      return {
        profile: {},
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

My dashboard component:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import Moment from 'react-moment'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { getCurrentProfile } from '../actions/profileActions'
import Loader from '../components/layout/Loader'
import DashboardActions from '../components/dashboard/DashboardActions'

const Dashboard = ({ history }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const profileDetails = useSelector((state) => state.profileDetails)
  const { loading, error, profile } = profileDetails

  const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin)
  const { userData } = userLogin

  console.log(profile)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!userData) {
      history.push('/login')
    } else {
      dispatch(getCurrentProfile())
    }
  }, [dispatch, history, userData])

  return (
    <>
      <h1 class='mb-4'>Dashboard</h1>
      <p>Welcome {userData && userData.name}</p>
      <br />
      {loading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <>
          <DashboardActions />
          <h2 className='my-2'>Education Details</h2>
          <table className='table'>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Level</th>
                <th>Field of study</th>
                <th>School</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>{profile.education.map((edu) => console.log(edu))}</tbody>
          </table>
        </>
      )}
    </>
  )
}

export default Dashboard
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

`state.profile.educatioin` is undefined in your initial state.

```
export const profileDetailsReducer = (state = { profile: {} }, action) => { ...
```

## Solution(s)

Define an initial state that contains an `education` array

```
const initialState = {
  profile: {
    education: [],
  },
};

export const profileDetailsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => { ...
```

Or provide a fallback value from your selector

```
const { loading, error, profile: { education = [] } } = profileDetails;

...

<tbody>{education.map((edu) => console.log(edu))}</tbody>
```

Or provide the fallback in the render

```
<tbody>{(profile.education ?? []).map((edu) => console.log(edu))}</tbody>
```